# I am getting an error "Unexpected token in JSON at position..."

Tags: node.js, json, angular

My Mongo JSON:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f9e0bebd5c7e2fdf70f1f58"},
"formAttributes":[
{"attributeName":"firstName","attributeType":"text"},
{"attributeName":"lastName","attributeType":"date"}
]}
```

When I run my nodejs api only, it gives the result correctly.

```
route.get('/all', (req, res) =>{
    FormAttributes.find((error, data) =>{
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
        else{
            res.send(data);
        }
    });
});
```

When I try to do this from Angular frontend, I get the error.

```
    this.sharedService.getAttributes().subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res)
      });
    }
```

My service:

```
  
  getAttributes(){
    const headerDict = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    }
    const requestOptions = {                                                                                                                                                                                 
      headers: new HttpHeaders(headerDict), 
    };

    return this.http.get('formattributes/all', requestOptions);
  }
```

I am not parsing JSON on my own anywhere. Why do I see this error:

```
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "<!doctype html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵  <meta ch…ipt src="main.js" defer></script></body>↵</html>↵"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/formattributes/all"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/formattributes/all"
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is a response header, not a request header. As far as the error goes, Angular's HttpClient automatically parses the JSON for you. The error occurs because the service is returning HTML when the HttpClient has been told to only accept `'application/json'`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Thanks for reply. But, when I run api only and check in the console: It logs as----> [
  {
    formAttributes: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    _id: 5f9e0bebd5c7e2fdf70f1f58
  }
]
In post man I see the proper data. Why do my service return HTML when the api is returning an object.

Comment: I have no idea. Have you tried hitting the exact same URL? I'd look at the network tab in your browser's developer tools and look at exactly what the entire response is. It's likely an HTML page of an error, like 404 Not Found or 500 Internal Server Error.